# How to get event details with calendar api v3

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to retrieve events details with the lastest api but I don't find any example.
This is my code for retreiving events:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$events = $service->events->listEvents('email');


foreach ($events->getItems() as $event)
{
  echo $event->getSummary()." ".$event->getId().": ".$event->getDescription()." "."<br><br>";
}
```

It works but I don't find the function to get other details like start and end time, is there somewhere these functions are listed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find by looking at the php client sources:

```
$event->getStart()->getDateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Calendar API v3 reference for event can be found here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource

It list the full set of attributes which belong to an event.

To get access to any event attribute, add `get` to the start of it and camelcase the result. Some example:

```
$event.getSummary()
$event.getStatus()
$event.getVisibility()
```

If the value you are after is an object itself then you can chain your gets:

```
$event.getStart().getDateTime()
$event.getOrganizer().getEmail()
```