# PHP accessing private members of an object

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I have seen this question once before but I am looking for a little more clarification related to my situation.  What I am trying to do is access event data from the google calendar api using php.  The data is returned in an object but the information I need to parse and use is protected.  I am not sure how to get around this.  This thread

[How to get protected property value of object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843616/how-to-get-protected-property-value-of-object-in-php)

is essentially identical to my current situation and it seems like the person found a solution yet didn't post any code or any sort of update to reflect what was done.  Hopefully some one can clarify it more.  Here is the code I am currently using, insight would be greatly appreciated

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$maxEvents = 100;
$minStartDate = date('c');
$maxEndDate = date('c',strtotime("+1 day"));

$calendarId = '<MY CALENDAR ID>';

putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<MY CREDENTIALS>");
$scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes($scope);
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$options = array(
    'maxResults'    => $maxEvents,
    'orderBy'       => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents'  => TRUE,
    'timeMin'       => $minStartDate,
    'timeMax'       => $maxEndDate,
);

$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $options);
$events = $results->getItems();

$num = count($events);
echo $num . '<br/>';
echo 'results<br><pre>';print_r($events); echo '</pre><br>';

echo $events[1]->summary;
print_r($events[1]->modelData['creator']->email);
```

The print_r statements show the following (I'm truncating it)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Google_Service_Calendar_Event Object
    (
        [collection_key:protected] => recurrence
        [anyoneCanAddSelf] => 
        [attachmentsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttachment
        [attachmentsDataType:protected] => array
        [attendeesType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee
        [attendeesDataType:protected] => array
        [attendeesOmitted] => 
        [colorId] => 
        [conferenceDataType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData
        [conferenceDataDataType:protected] => 
        [created] => 2017-11-02T18:29:30.000Z
        [creatorType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator
        [creatorDataType:protected] => 
        [description] => 
Original Schedule Date - 2018-12-12
        [endType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime
        [endDataType:protected] => 
        [endTimeUnspecified] => 
        [etag] => "3034871549678000"
        [extendedPropertiesType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties
        [extendedPropertiesDataType:protected] => 
        [gadgetType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventGadget
        [gadgetDataType:protected] => 
        [guestsCanInviteOthers] => 
        [guestsCanModify] => 
        [guestsCanSeeOtherGuests] => 
        [hangoutLink] => 
        [htmlLink] => 
        [iCalUID] => 
        [id] => 
        [kind] => calendar#event
        [location] => 
        [locked] => 
        [organizerType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventOrganizer
        [organizerDataType:protected] => 
        [originalStartTimeType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime
        [originalStartTimeDataType:protected] => 
        [privateCopy] => 
        [recurrence] => 
        [recurringEventId] => 
        [remindersType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders
        [remindersDataType:protected] => 
        [sequence] => 2
        [sourceType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventSource
        [sourceDataType:protected] => 
        [startType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime
        [startDataType:protected] => 
        [status] => confirmed
        [summary] => 
        [transparency] => 
        [updated] => 2018-01-31T21:56:14.839Z
        [visibility] => 
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
                [creator] => Array
                    (
                        [email] => 
                        [displayName] => 
                    )

                [organizer] => Array
                    (
                        [email] => 
                        [self] => 1
                    )

                [start] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2018-07-25
                    )

                [end] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2018-07-26
                    )

                [attendees] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [email] => 
                                [responseStatus] => needsAction
                            )

                    )

                [reminders] => Array
                    (
                        [useDefault] => 1
                    )

            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

Like the post from the link I posted I too am looking to access the start and end dates of each event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the value of a private property with Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604946/can-i-get-the-value-of-a-private-property-with-reflection)

Comment: There should be a `getSomething` method to get what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064642/how-to-get-event-details-with-calendar-api-v3

Comment: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Event.html there are some methods that will help you

Comment: thanks for the replies, using the methods to retrieve the start date still throws and error, maybe because I am using the listEvents method because I need to grab dates within a range and will not have a specific event id to use.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: You should loop through the array returned by `listEvents()` and call the methods on the elements.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment in the question you linked to, you can use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), which returns an associative array containing the non-static properties of the object.

```
print_r(get_object_vars($events[1])['modelData']['creator']->email);
```

Comment: doing that tells me that 

Notice: Undefined index: modelData in

Comment: What does `var_dump(get_object_vars($events[1]))` show?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your help, it pointed me in the right direction.  I found the following solution

```
    $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $options);

    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        echo "Summary:  ", $event->getSummary(), "<br/>";
        echo "Location: ", $event->getLocation(), "<br/>";
        echo "Start:    ", parse_date($event->getStart()), "<br/>";
        echo "End:      ", parse_date($event->getEnd()), "<br/>";
        echo '<br/>';
    }

    function parse_date($date){
        $val = $date->getDate();
        return (new DateTime($val))->format('d/m/Y');
    }
```

This at least gives me the information I need which will be used in other functions.